# BIO_set_conn_hostname & BIO_get_ssl missing from libssl-1_1.dll (OpenSSL)

Tags: openssl, dtls, tls-psk

I am trying to implement DTLS with PSK security in Delphi using the OpenSSL library. The C++ example I am basing this on calls "BIO_set_conn_hostname" and "BIO_get_ssl" but these functions do not appear to be in "libssl-1_1.dll".
The OpenSSL documentation suggest that these functions should be in version 1.1 but I have interrogated the DLL and they are definitely not there - where should I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these are C macros defined in openssl/bio.h:

```
/usr/include/openssl/bio.h:#  define BIO_set_conn_hostname(b,name) BIO_ctrl(...)
/usr/include/openssl/bio.h:# define BIO_get_ssl(b,sslp) BIO_ctrl(...)
```

Credit to Viktor Dukhovni who answered this on the openSSL mailing list.